# How to save build logs from Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

Currently, the way I have my pipelines setup is having each step run on 'self.hosted' runners. I do it this way so I don't have to spend Bitbucket build minutes. Every time the pipeline runs, I can see the containers being created and terminated on my Docker application. The only debugging method I have found is by clicking on the container with the "build" word in it. Inside the container, I can see all the logs; every project build step and tests.
I'm trying to find a way to save these build logs into a text file and download it as an artifact. Bitbucket has a guide to [generate support logs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/generate-support-logs/) but none of the logs are build logs.